# How do I get all values for Store_ID pulled into my Snowflake Query?

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a query below and am trying to get all the week_id's, upc_id's and upc_dsc's pulled in even if there is no net_amt or item_qty for them. I'm successfully pulling in all stores, but I also want to show a upc and week id for these stores so that they can see if they have 0 sales for a upc. I tried doing a right join with my date table under the right join of the s table as well as a right join for the upc table, but it messes up my data and doesn't pull in the columns I need. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you

```
  select 
   a.week_id
  , s.district_cd
  , s.store_id
  , a.upc_id
  , a.upc_dsc
  , sum(a.net_amt) as current_week_sales
  , sum(t.net_amt) as last_week_sales
  , sum(a.item_qty) as current_week_units
  , sum(t.item_qty) as last_week_units

  from (
  
select 
 week_id
, district_cd
, str.store_id
, txn.upc_id
, upc_dsc
, dense_rank() over (order by week_id) as rank   
, sum(txn.net_amt) as net_amt
, sum(txn.item_qty) as item_qty

from dw_dss.txn_facts  txn

left join dw_dss.lu_store_finance_om  STR  
on str.store_id = txn.store_id
 join dw_dss.lu_upc upc
on upc.upc_id = txn.upc_id
 join lu_day_merge day
on day.d_date = txn.txn_dte
where district_cd in (72,73)
and txn.upc_id in (27610100000
,27610200000
,27610300000
,27610400000
)
and division_id = 19
and txn_dte between '2021-07-25' and current_date - 1
group by 1,2,3,4,5

) a

left join temp_tables.ab_week_ago t
on t.rank = a.rank and a.store_id = t.store_id and a.upc_id = t.upc_id

right join dw_dss.lu_store_finance_om s 
on s.store_id = a.store_id

where s.division_id = 19
and s.district_cd in (72,73)

group by 1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a smaller table and a smaller query? This one is too long to debug, and probably we can apply the same principles to a smaller example

Comment: Define your tables and columns clearly, and how they relate to your problem.  It's often best to include an *executable* test case, with complete SQL, with data and expected results.  Don't include unnecessary detail in the test case.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in a previous comment, the example is too long to debug, especially since the source tables are not provided.

However, as a general rule, when adding zeroes for missing dimensions, I follow these steps:

1. Construct the main query, this is the query with all the complexity
   that pulls the data you need - just the available data, without
   missing dimensions; test this query to make sure it gives correct
   results, aggregated correctly by each dimension
2. Then use this query as a CTE in a WITH statement and to this query, you can right join all dimensions for which you want to add zero values for missing data
3. Be sure to double check filtering on the dimensions to ensure that you don't filter out too much in your WHERE conditions, for example, instead of filtering with WHERE on the final query, like in your example:

```
right join dw_dss.lu_store_finance_om s 
on s.store_id = a.store_id

where s.division_id = 19
and s.district_cd in (72,73)
```

I might rather filter the dimension itself in a subquery:

```
right join (select store_id from dw_dss.lu_store_finance_om 
            where s.division_id = 19 and s.district_cd in (72,73)) s 
on s.store_id = a.store_id
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a query below and am trying to get all the week_id's, upc_id's and upc_dsc's pulled in even if there is no net_amt or item_qty for them.

You want to generate the rows that you want using `cross join` and then use `left join` to bring in the the data you want.  In your case, you also want aggregation.

You have not explained the tables, and I find your query quite hard to follow.  But the idea is:

```
select c.weekid, c.store_id, c.upc_id,
       count(f.dayid) as num_sales,
       sum(f.net_amt) as total_amt
from calendar c cross join
     stores s cross join
     upcs u left join
     facts f
     using (dayid, store_id, upc_id)  -- or whatever the right conditions are
group by c.weekid, c.store_id, c.upc_id;
```

Obviously, you have additional filters.  You would apply these filters in the `where` clause to the dimension tables (or use a subquery if the logic is more complicated).